# How to know the index of the iterator when using map in Julia

Tags: julia, map-function

I have an Array of arrays, called `y`:

```
y=Array(Vector{Int64}, 10)
```

which is basically a list of 1-dimensional arrays(10 of them), and each 1-dimensional array has length 5. Below is an example of how they are initialized:

```
for i in 1:10
    y[i]=sample(1:20, 5)
end
```

Each 1-dimensional array includes 5 randomly sampled integers between `1` to `20`.

Right now I am applying a map function where for each of those 1-dimensional arrays in `y` , excludes which numbers from `1` to `20`:

```
map(x->setdiff(1:20, x), y)
```

However, I want to make sure when the function applied to `y[i]`, if the output of `setdiff(1:20, y[i])` includes `i`, `i` is excluded from the results. in other words I want a function that works like

```
setdiff(deleteat!(Vector(1:20),i) ,y[i])
```

but with `map`.

Mainly my question is that whether you can access the index in the `map` function.

P.S, I know how to do it with `comprehensions`, I wanted to know if it is possible to do it with map.

comprehension way:

```
[setdiff(deleteat!(Vector(1:20), index), value) for (index,value) in enumerate(y)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
map(x -> setdiff(deleteat!(Vector(1:20), x[1]),x[2]), enumerate(y))
```

For your example gives this:

> [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,17,19,20]
>   [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,16,17,18,20]
>   ....
>   [1,2,4,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
>   [1,2,3,5,6,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20]

Comment: You can use destructuring in the lambda to avoid the indexing: 

`map(((i,yi), ) -> setdiff(deleteat!(Vector(1:20), i), yi), enumerate(y))`

A little ugly with the `((i,yi), ) ->` but necessary to have `(i,yi)` parsed as a tuple argument.